# Lebesgue decomposition

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f\geq 0$ be integrable over $X$ wrt to $\mu$. How can I find the Lebesgue decomposition wrt $\mu$ of the measure $\lambda(E) = \int_E fd\mu $ for every $E\in M$.

So I know I must find measures $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ such that $\lambda = \lambda_1+\lambda_2$, with $\lambda_1 \perp \mu$ and $\lambda_2 \ll \mu.$  Please  how do I proceed?

Comment: Note that your $\lambda$ is already absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: Yes...I know that.

Comment: The null measure is perpendicular and f is the abs. continuous!

Comment: @chessmath I don't understand what you mean. can you elaborate?

Comment: The decomposition you are looking for is $\lambda=0+\lambda$.